# Finding the nearest/closest value in a collection but not exceeding it

Tags: kotlin

I have a collection and want to return the nearest value to some fixed value but not exceed the fixed value. For example, if my collection looks like this:

```
val numbers = mutableListOf(23, 12, 64, 47, 36, 55)
```

and I have a target fixed value of 35, the value returned from the collection would be 23. Here are some other examples:

```
Target -> Returned
29 -> 23
5 -> null (there is no value less than 12, so null is returned)
70 -> 64
```

Is there some Collection function that I can use that would provide the expected result? Note: The list of numbers is not sorted. In the real app, these are not numbers but objects that do contain an integer property, but I could just as well sort the collection first on that value if that would help in the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `fold` function to hold the closest value in an accumulator. For instance,

```
val numbers = mutableListOf(23, 12, 64, 47, 36, 55)

val target = 35

val answer = numbers.fold(null){acc: Int?, num ->
    if(num <= target && (acc == null || num > acc)) num
    else acc
}
```

In case you want to break the loop if the target matches one of the values in the list you can have the following

```
val numbers = mutableListOf(23, 12, 64, 47, 36, 55)
val target = 35

fun MutableList<Int>.findClosest(input: Int) = fold(null) { acc: Int?, num ->
    val closest = if (num <= input && (acc == null || num > acc)) num else acc
    if (closest == input) return@findClosest closest else return@fold closest
}

val answer = numbers.findClosest(target)
```

The `return` keyword in the inner function will return from `findClosest` function as soon as the target matches a particular value

Comment: The line "if (closest == input) return closest else closest" returns closest regardless. That looks like a bug?

Comment: yes, it seems weird, but the `return` actually returns from the outer function, while the `else` part is just for the lambda within `fold` . you can visualize it as `if (closest == input) return closest else return@fold closest`

Comment: Why do we have to write `as Int?` (for example) when we give null value inside the fold? How come it cannot infer the type of an initial value from the type of the elements in the collection?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any function from the library that would solve it, but you can define your own extension as

```
fun <T: Comparable<T>> Iterable<T>.findPredecessor(value: T): T?{
        var currentCandidate: T? = null
        this.filter { it < value }. forEach {
            currentCandidate = when {
                currentCandidate == null -> it
                currentCandidate!! < it  -> it
                else -> currentCandidate
            }
        }
        return currentCandidate
    }
```

Also if this is a one-two time operation then you are ok with iteration, otherwise you should sort the input and then use a modified binary search.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`minByOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/min-by-or-null.html). You want to find the number with the minimum difference from `target`. But before doing that, you should `filter` out those that are more than `target`.

```
numbers.filter { it <= target }.minByOrNull { target - it }
```

This will loop through `numbers` twice. If you don't like that, you can add [`asSequence()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html) before `.filter`.

Comment: This is nice but after running some tests, it is almost twice as slow as the solution by sidgate. Still, for small collections, very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would use

```
numbers.asSequence().filter { it <= target }.maxOfOrNull()
```

I think it's self-explanatory.